# Correctness of "He took to drink..."

Tags: phrases, verb-forms

> He **took to drink** to lessen his mental tension.

I think that "took to drink" is incorrect, and think that it should be "drink**ing**" instead because the `-ing` form is always used with the present participle of the verb.

Am I correct? Please elaborate on usage of `-ing`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["He **took to drink**" is actually a perfectly legitimate English phrase](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/take-to-drink) meaning "to begin regularly consuming alcohol".

For example:

> [Prisoner went to work in a mill, and afterwards as a labourer in a shipyard, where he **took to drink** when about 17.](https://books.google.com/books?id=2ZEOAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA57&dq=%22he%20took%20to%20drink%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQiey7hLjRAhXGxxQKHcZkDeMQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22he%20took%20to%20drink%22&f=false)

[**Drink** in this context is actually a noun, not a verb!](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drink)  However, [it's a rather old-fashioned usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=took%20to%20drink&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctook%20to%20drink%3B%2Cc0) that you won't hear very much any more.

So is it correct?  Yes, technically it is.  You are correct in thinking that if it were a verb, it would have to be an -ing form, like "He took to **eating**."

Comment: Do all the verbs use "ing" ?

Comment: @Garrick The gerund form is *-ing* for all verbs that have a gerund form; a handful of defective verbs do not, like *ought* or *beware*.

Comment: "He took to drink like a fish takes to water"

Answer (score 0):

This is an annoying regional thing, some speakers absolutely use the phrase "took to drink" especially in British English. The use of the word "drink" in this context refers specifically to alcohol and not other liquids. The phrase "driven to drink" appears commonly in most english speaking countries to refer to a person who has taken to alcoholism in response to stress, and so:

> "He took to drink to lessen his mental tension"

Is clunky, but not strictly wrong, and clearly is meant to indicate that "he" is an alcoholic. In fact, the part that sounds the worse is the "mental tension" part. I would phrase it something like

> "He took to drink on account of his emotional problems"

or

> "Extreme stress drove him to drink"

However,

> "He took to drinking to lessen his mental tension"

Is also not wrong.

Comment: -1 because I don't think you can reasonably dismiss [***to take to***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/take+to) as "an annoying regional thing". The three definitions there are 1. *To have recourse to; go to, as for safety: **took to the woods.*** 2. *To develop as a habit or a steady practice: **take to drink.*** 3. *To become fond of or attached to: "**Two keen minds that they are, they took to each other**" (Jack Kerouac).* All of which seem like pretty standard mainstream English to me, not "clunky" at all.

Comment: I think you took offense to something where nothing was intended. The "drink" as a noun case is indeed more common in the UK with phrases like "drink driving" that don't appear typically in American english. The "clunky" part of the phrase if you actually will read my comment was the "lessen his mental tension", because I don't like the flow of that phrase, not the "took to drink" part. As I pointed out, the phrasing is legitimate and unlikely to be misunderstood.

Comment: I'm not sure *to lessen his mental tension* is any less "clunky" than *on account of his emotional problems* (though they carry significantly different nuances anyway). And I don't think *to take to drink* is particularly BrE rather than AmE (the fact that we also use it as a noun adjunct in the more recent *drink driving* is scarcely relevant to the long-established idiom being examined). But you do seem to be saying use of ***drink*** as a noun (as opposed to the gerund noun ***drinking***) is a "regionalism", which is essentially the point I'm taking issue with.

Comment: "Took to drink" is, if anything, more literary than regional.  It's not uncommon in AmE writing.

Comment: @Andrew: You're right - it's definitely more "literary" than "regional, dialectal". Looking at NGrams in this area, I'm somewhat surprised to find that over recent decades, [the demon drink](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+demon+drink&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20demon%20drink%3B%2Cc0) has apparently become *way* more common in BrE than AmE. Which seems odd because it strikes me as having significant "religious" connotations, but we Brits are practically heathens compared to the US.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm inclined to agree with you although at this point in this country's history there is at least 50% of the American population I can't understand.  Anyway looking at the references using "demon drink", most seem historical and the rest ironic.

Comment: @Andrew: Good point. Now I've just drilled down into BrE "demon drink" in my link, I see there are far less instances than the graph itself might imply, and an awful lot of the later ones are clearly ironic. Perhaps any US/UK split doesn't so much reflect Brits being more *aware* of the harm drink can cause, but rather that we're more willing to poke fun at the situation (hopefully, while still recognising that it *is* a potentially serious issue).